# how to avoid characters stacking in EditText in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

I created a EditText and set maxLenght to 200. But when I type more than 200 characters and try to erase the text, first it erases the characters that are not shown. How do I avoid this?

Comment: It doesn't matter if they're shown or not, all android:maxLength will do is make sure the textview doesn't have more than 200 characters.

Comment: But I don't want to erase the unshown characters. If I type more than 200 characters I want to erase it immediately

Comment: If there are characters that are unshown, it means that they are part of the 200 characters. maxLength just controls the contents of the textview, not the size of the textview.

Comment: Ok, but how do I make it do what I want?

Comment: So you want the width of the EditText to be big enough to fit 200 characters?

Comment: Yes, up to 200 characters,

Comment: Would you be ok with the textview being several lines long so that it can fit all the characters?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using multiple lines for your EditText add `android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"`, then all 200 characters will fit into the EditText.

Comment: I'm already using this. The problem is that when I type more than 200 characters and try to erase the text it will firstly erase the characters that are not shown(characters above 200), and I don't want this to happen.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the number for android:lines or android:maxLines?

Comment: I'm not sure. If you increase android:lines, is it at least making it so all your text fits on the screen?

Comment: if you set `android:lines="5"` do all of the characters appear on the screen.

Comment: If I do this the erase problem overs, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, thats what Im trying to say.

Comment: And I can't just set a number of lines. I can't Depend on the device's screen size, because the text lenght will change, and I don't want it to happen.

Comment: Post all text related to EditText (Java and XML)

Comment: I just have this, no java code. I put it as  an answer.

Comment: Ahh but you didnt follow what i said! You need `text|textMultiLine`

Comment: Isn't it `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

Comment: No its a combination of two flags. The | symbol (Binary or) combines the two.

Comment: Just copy exactly what my answer says!

Comment: Did you also try setting android:lines or android:maxLines?

Comment: yup did all this stuff

Comment: Ok at this point i dont know, i would just ask this question again as "cant get EditText multiline to work" and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/fieldDescription"
            android:hint="Descrição(até 200 caracteres)"
            android:maxLength="200"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
```